# Compiling Compass in an Ember-CLI project

Tags: ember.js, compass-sass, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli v0.0.23, and am trying to get the [broccoli-compass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/broccoli-compass) package working with my project, and I've run into some problems.

First, in my `Brocfile`, I have replaced the standard Ember-CLI "blueprint" version of:

```
var styles = preprocessCss(appAndDependencies, prefix + '/styles', '/assets');
```

with the following:

```
var compileCompass = require('broccoli-compass');
var styles = compileCompass(appAndDependencies, 'app/styles/app.scss', {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    sassDir: 'app/styles',
    imagesDir: 'public/images/'
});
```

However, when I run an `ember build`, I receive the following output:

```
$ ember build
[broccoli-compass] Error:  Command failed: Errno::ENOENT on line ["155"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.6/lib/compass/compiler.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/gaker/Sites/project/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-GrWa8Zva.tmp/app/styles/app.scss
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace. The command-line arguments was: `compass compile app/styles/app.scss --relative-assets --sass-dir app/styles --output-style expanded --images-dir public/images/ --css-dir "../compass_compiler-tmp_dest_dir-eFsq51BG.tmp"`
```

If I try to run the `compass` command that is output in the error in my terminal, it does create the file, only it is up one directory from my project root (notice `--css-dir` in the output).

I have tried many combinations of options `sassDir`, `imagesDir`, etc when calling `compileCompass` and this is the closest I've gotten.

So any ideas on what I can do to successfully get compass, broccoli-compass and ember-cli playing nicely?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (added prefix and cssDir):

```
var compileCompass = require('broccoli-compass');
var styles = compileCompass(appAndDependencies, prefix + '/styles/app.scss', {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    sassDir: prefix + '/styles',
    imagesDir: 'public/images/',
    cssDir: '/assets'
});
```

Steffen

Comment: @ steffen : As of ember-cli v0.0.28 - where does this go? In  Brocfile.js somewhere? I'm not sure where to put these within the project, and suspect that it might have changes since v0.0.23.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ember-cli-compass-compiler](https://github.com/quaertym/ember-cli-compass-compiler) addon to compile compass in ember-cli apps.

Just do the following in your ember-cli app:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-compass-compiler
```

This is all you need to do, everything works as expected from now on. It compiles your `appname.scss` file into `appname.css` on `ember build` or `ember serve` command.

Comment: (Tested in 0.0.40) the compiling part works, but i can't reference images that are in public/assets/images (or another directory). The URL will be http://localhost:4200/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-HoagpjbQ.tmp/images/logo.png (or similar) and the image can't be found.

Comment: (0.0.40) We're now adding this to the `Brocfile.js`: `var app = new EmberApp({ compassOptions: { imagesDir: '../assets/images/' } });` note the relative imagesDir - this way it works on mac and win.

Comment: @amenthes yep, that's the way you override default options. I will investigate this, `assets/images/` may be a good default, then I will  release a new version.

Comment: the problem is pushing it to Heroku: 
`version: 0.0.44`
`BuildingBuilding./bin/sh: compass: not found`

Comment: Do you need to have broccoli-sass installed also to get this working? I had both installed and I can't get any sass to compile now, even after removing broccoli-sass I still can't get any sass to compile, also not getting any errors in the terminal when I save a sass file. The app.css file is completely blank no matter how many times I save.

Comment: @Jordan You do not need broccoli-sass if you installed it please remove. You should also need to have an `app.scss` file in your styles folder.

Comment: @quaertym I removed it and I had a app.scss in their but it was not working, when I changed it to the title of my app it worked. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @Jordan yes, sorry for the misleading comment before. Filename should be `appname.scss` as mentioned in the answer.