# Broccoli-compass and ember-cli 0.39

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I recently upgraded ember-cli to .39, and something changed to cause my broccoli-compass code to break.

Here's the code:

```
app.styles = function() {
  return compileCompass(this.appAndDependencies(), this.name + '/styles/app.scss', {
    compassCommand: 'bundle exec compass',
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    sassDir: this.name + '/styles',
    imagesDir: 'public/images',
    cssDir: '/assets'
  });
};
```

I get this error:

```
[broccoli-compass] Error:  Command failed: Errno::ENOENT on line ["155"] of ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/compass-0.12.6/lib/compass/compiler.rb: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ~/campaign-designer/ember/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-pSk32Zuy.tmp/campaign-designer/styles/app.scss
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

arguments: `bundle exec compass compile campaign-designer/styles/app.scss --relative-assets --sass-dir campaign-designer/styles --output-style expanded --images-dir public/images --css-dir "../compass_compiler-tmp_cache_dir-8Yu97OaF.tmp/assets"`
```

Has `app.styles` or `this.appAndDependencies()` changed? I've tried many variants of this config to no avail.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365966/replace-broccoli-sass-with-broccoli-compass-in-broccoli-sample-app), but I still couldn't get things working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, something like this ended up helping me:

```
// Compass config in Brocfile.js
app.registry.add('css', 'broccoli-compass', 'scss', {
  toTree: function(tree, inputPath, outputPath, options) {
    // broccoli-compass doesn't like leading slashes
    if (inputPath[0] === '/') { inputPath = inputPath.slice(1); }

    // tree = mergeTrees([
    //   tree,
    //   'public'
    // ], {
    //   description: 'TreeMerger (stylesAndVendorAndPublic)'
    // });

    return compileCompass(tree, inputPath + '/app.scss', {
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      // require: 'sass-css-importer', // Allows us to import CSS files with @import("CSS:path")
      sassDir: inputPath,
      imagesDir: 'images',
      //fontsDir: 'fonts',
      cssDir: outputPath
    });
  }
});
```

Ultimately I removed compass from my project (I just had to write a few SASS mixins myself) to avoid the troubles with the config + attempt to get faster build speeds.

---

**Update:** You may now want to check out the [ember-cli-compass-compiler](https://github.com/quaertym/ember-cli-compass-compiler) ember-cli addon, which makes it easier to get started with Compass in your ember-cli project.