# How to replace broccoli-sass with broccoli-ruby-sass

Tags: ember-cli

I've been told I need to replace use broccoli-sass with broccoli-ruby-sass, due to bug/lack of support with @extend functionality in LibSass.

So .. do I just install broccoli-ruby-sass with npm? Also uninstall broccoli-sass? Or do I need a more complicated approach in my brocfile.js as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365966/replace-broccoli-sass-with-broccoli-compass-in-broccoli-sample-app)?

Any help appreciated. I'm pretty much a noob here and need all the help I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a chance to try a few things. The following seemed to work:

1. `$ npm install broccoli-ruby-sass --save-dev`
2. Remove dependency for broccoli-sass from package.json

So pretty easy. I should have had a bit more courage.

Note to readers who may wish to do the same: LibSass is noticeably faster than Ruby Sass, but I understand it is newer, still lacks some features, and in my case had apparent bugs. So I had no choice.